# How do you divide the Muzzarella pizza into 7 parts?

Tags: google-doodles

The [current Google doodle](https://g.co/doodle/xds69wp) in my region is about dividing pizzas into different numbers of slices. I am stuck at level 5 where you have a to divide a *Muzzarella* pizza **into 7 slices using at most 3 cuts**. How do I do that?

[image]

I think I need to get to the state where I have 1+3 slices and then double the 3 to get 1+3+3=7 but I don't know how.

Comment: What I want to know is how you do the final level (desert pizza).

Comment: @nick012000 post it as a new question, I have that screenshot too

Comment: @nick012000 The last and the ninth pizza just seem like a chore that I skipped. It's not a new idea that requires some thinking but just needs the visual sorting of colored shapes.

Comment: As I just learned, it's also a matter of making sure that *each slice* has at least one olive on it.

Answer (score 34):

This solution worked for me, see picture:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132142/discussion-on-answer-by-pinckerman-how-do-you-divide-the-muzzarella-pizza-into-7).